# Developing for android with QBASIC?

Tags: qbasic, qb64

I have read that you can make programs for android with qbasic. Is it possible and if it is does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: https://apkpure.com/qbasic-compiler/com.RetroDoSoft.QBasic

Comment: Simply run QBasic insider of DosBox. Or you might use SmallBasic instead https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.smallbasic
Note before someone saying different neither QB64 or QuickBasic. While QBasic is an interpreter, QuickBasic is an compiler. QB64 is only an transpiller that converts to c code and then use some c compiler. You could use this c code in you android app. But this question is about QBasic and that runs well on DOS emulation in Android Systems.

Comment: QB64 (a derivative of Qbasic) has the capability to compile to Windows/Linux/MACosX and android.

Answer (score 2):

The Android experiment was short-lived and we have scraped the module from the latest version of QB64, especially because it was not compatible with the latest version of Android Studio anymore.

While it lasted, a few "Hello World" samples were successfully compiled and ran on android devices, but that was as far as it went. Sorry about that.